# `p12` file work in Firefox RestClient but not work in WebSphere

Tags: java, websphere, keystore, client-certificates, p12

I have a java web application that runs in WebSphere that need to call to third party service (IBM) to get some response.

At first IBM give me a `p12` file, which is contain client certificate, and I test it in Firefox `RestClient`, the call success and I am getting response code 200 in the `RestClient`. Else, I will get 403 forbidden. So this is proof that the `p12` provided by third party is correct. Please correct me if my statement is wrong.

Thus, I happily import this `p12` file into my CellDefaultKeyStore to test the connection on my application. Unfortunately, after I import this p12 file, the nodes status become "unknown", and I cant even "synchronize" them. And when I check server log, I keep seeing

```
com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by xxx is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
```

After that I remove it from `CellDefaultKeyStore` try to import it into `NodeDefaultKeyStore`, the node issue gone, the node can sync back and my app can call to the third party successfully. I think this is done of my job today, however, this solution is not stable, its only work some times, not every time. The node status will still become "unknown" after a moment, or, if I run `./stopManager.sh` and `./startManager.sh`, the node issue will immediately come back.

I have try run `./stopNode.sh` and `./startNode.sh`, there are no error in the log of this 2 shell script. But the WAS Console UI there still showing status is `unknown`, and I cant even stop start my server through WAS Console.

At first I am thinking its maybe display issue, but this issue will solve if I delete the `p12` file from my `NodeDefaultKeyStore`.

I try google around but end up still cant find any clue. I am not sure is it my configuration or the `p12` file having problem.

Which log should I refer to see why the node status will become `unknown`, or what else I can continue to debug/troubleshoot on this?

Comment: At the moment I'm not quite following all that your have done.  One again I really need to see configuration and trace to understand what you have done.  The stack you have above is partial.   The System out logs should give a detailed message about what certificate needs to be added to what Truststore.  Is that in the logs?

Comment: When you install to any of the built-in keystores, if you make it the _default_ certificate, that will cause node synchronization issues. Instead, you give it a different alias, and then need to specify that alias like in the  Dynamic outbound endpoint SSL configurations

Answer (score 0):

You received the certificate for an external service and you want code in Websphere to connect to that service right?  The default cell store is not the place to put external connection`s certificates.

Put it in the Trusted keystore.  This will tell WebSphere to trust that external connections certificate, enabling your code to connect to it.

You can do it via the console, or using iKeyman directly on the file.

That being said, do not mess with the default certificate in the default keystore.  @dbreaux is right on that in the comments.